# Minecraft chunk generation via version

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

So in minecraft  if i make a copy of a world (that has not been explored yet) and explore on the copy will the original world have the same chunk generation (same biomes, caves, structures, etc) as the copy (yet original still not explored) or will the original update according to the version?

Comment: What you are referring to is world generation, not chunk loading, and new chunks will be generated accordingly to the game version, if the version is the same then the world will always be the same.

Answer (score 1):

The chunks that have already been generated will retain their state.

Chunks that have not been generated will generate in on the current version. This applies to any situation, for example just using a world from an older update. The current version is used.

Answer (score -1):

I'm glad I can help you.

The following is my personal opinion.

First of all, we need to understand that if we copy a world, the seed of the world itself will not change. When minecraft generates the world, there is a set of complex algorithms that will not change. Just because it will not change, when inputting the same seed (equivalent to copying a map that has not been explored), it will not change, The generated world is exactly the same. Minecraft's world does not generate a new block temporarily when the player moves out of the block or visual range, but it is calculated by default at the moment when the seed is set to load the world. However, in order to save memory, it will only load an area where you are, otherwise it will occupy more memory than you think.

Secondly, if you play in the old world with the new version, the things in the old world that have not been removed in the current version still exist, and the material will change with the new version. But if something is removed, the situation will be very complicated.

In addition: remember not to play with the old version of the new version of the world, otherwise the new content will be considered unknown box (or entity) and replaced with air (which also means that it is useless to load in the new version again)!

Comment: this is a non answer

Comment: It's a bit unclear what the final answer is. Could you [edit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/381827/edit) in a phrase saying directly what the answer is? I could tell you tried to answer it but it's a bit hard to tell the final answer.